# Can Data Retention Settings delete only SOME records?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have consulted [this documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_manage_data_retention_policy.htm&type=5) and [this documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_manage_de_policies.htm&type=5) and [this Trailhead material](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-contact-management/manage-contact-data), but I can't find a concrete answer on this.  If I use Data Retention, can I configure it so that it only deletes specific records older than X days within a Data Extension?

For instance, say I have a Data Extension named myDE, and it contains some records that are 8 days old, and other records that are 2 days old.  Say I specify Retention settings on this DE of "Individual Records" and "After 7 Days".  When the nightly deletion process runs, will it ONLY delete the 8-day-old rows, and leave my 2-day-old rows intact within the DE?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can delete individual records based on how old they are.

Choose the „Individual Records” option and set after how many days they should be deleted:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I'm familiar w/ both of those settings, and I mentioned them in my question.  I just couldn't find in the documentation where it ever mentions that the rest of the DE will be left intact.